# How to expand source files when installing packages using MiKTeX

Tags: packages, installing, miktex

When installing packages using the MiKTeX Package Manager, there is usually a file placed in `texmf\source` whose name ends in `-src.tar.bz2` (or sometimes `-src.cab`).  These compressed files generally contain source code for the installed packages, but there are some packages where the compressed file contains additional documentation, sample files, or test files that are not installed anywhere else.  Is there some way to set the Package Manager to expand these files automatically?  For example, the `ut-thesis` package's `README` file refers to a `ut-thesis.tex` template file, but the template file is nowhere to be found other than compressed inside `texmf\source\ut-thesis-src.tar.bz2`, and there is no instruction directing the user to look there.  Similarly, the `hyperref` package contains lots of test files in `texmf\source\hyperref-src.tar.bz2` that are not installed anywhere else.  It would be nice if there were some way to ensure that these files are all expanded whenever a package is installed.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I see, there is no such opportunity in the MiKTeX Package Manager.

You can always extract the missing files yourself into a [local texmf](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69483/create-a-local-texmf-tree-in-miktex) tree or write a bug report in the [MiKTeX Bug Tracker](https://sourceforge.net/p/miktex/bugs/) (in my eyes these are bugs, if there is an explicit mention in one of the installed documentation files).

If you are unsure, you could ask first Christian Schenk (the MiKTeX maintainer) in general, how to proceed, see [MiKTeX: Contact](http://miktex.org/contact).

Comment: Is it a bug with MiKTeX, or should the package author have done something differently to have a particular file installed?

Comment: See my edit. If you opt to ask Ch. Schenk, then add his reply here, please.

Comment: I opened a bug report [here](http://sourceforge.net/p/miktex/bugs/2204/) so we'll see what happens.